# folder permissions and sftp

Tags: linux, centos, sftp

I'm trying to set folder permissions on a linux machine. I have this primary folder: /home/master/staging

This folder houses subfolders containing user sftp drop points. I need to set folder permissions for this.

I have the following users:

MASTER
sftpuser1
sftpuser2

Master's home directory is /home/MASTER

I have done the following to the folder /home/master/staging/:

```
drwxrwx---. 19 MASTER MASTER  4096 Apr 14 02:21 .
drwxrwx---.  6 MASTER MASTER   199 Mar  5 12:20 ..
drwxrwx---.  2 MASTER MASTER    10 Apr 15 00:51 MASTER
drwxrwxr-x.  2 sftpuser1 MASTER    10 Apr 15 00:28 sftpuser1
drwxrwxr-x.  2 sftpuser2 MASTER    10 Feb 15 08:02 sftpuser2
```

Assuming MASTER is the group owner of group MASTER, I read the following on this:

```
MASTER "should" be able to read/write all folders
sftpuser1 should be able to read/write in folder /staging/sftpuser1
sftpuser2 should be able to read/write in folder /staging/sftpuser2
```

sftpuser1 and 2 have been set this way:

```
usermod sftpuser1 -s /bin/false
usermod sftpuser1 -d /home/master/staging/sftpuser1
usermod sftpuser2 -s /bin/false
usermod sftpuser2 -d /home/master/staging/sftpuser2
```

With that all being said, neither sftpusers cannot see their own folder using sftp, and user MASTER cannot go into the two sftpuser folders locally. all permission denied.

what am I missing here? The goal is sftpuser1 only sees sftpuser1; sftpuser2 only sees sftpuser2; and MASTER should be able to see all of them. Thanks!

## UPDATE #1:

MASTER is now able to see the sftpuser's folders.  Group privs fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "group owner of group" (as well as "folders" in *nix, lets call that as its supposed to be - directory). There is owner which are user, and there is group and others in traditional *nix permissions.

As you've already fixed access from MASTER user, you need to allow sftpuserX to access. But your parent directory /home/master allows only MASTER user and MASTER group to access it. That is why your sftpuserX can't get access to /home/master/sftpuserX directory.

Unless you are running sftp in a chroot environment it's not a good idea for such setup. Because if you allow sftpuserX to read /home/master directory they will get access to every file in MASTER user homedir actually.

I'd rather suggest you to create a separate directories for these users like /home/master/sftpuserX, change it's group to MASTER and allow g+rwx (full group access) to that directory (retaining sftpuserX as owner and full access). You can add a symlinks from /home/master/ to /home/sftpuserX directories if you really need to access them from there.

As an alternative take a look at extended permissions with ACLs (check for getfacl & setfacl commands). They allow more flexibility with permissions, but can become more complicated to manage.

Comment: ok.  I've created /home/sftpuserX.  the sftp does connect...but one thing bugs me.  in /home/sftpuserX sits the bashrc files.  I created a subfolder called files. so now I have /home/sftpuserX/files.  How do I restrict SFTP access to that location?  Thanks.

Comment: @arcee123 You can delete those user files like bashrc if user can't login (you've set shell to /bin/false) they won't be created again. If you really want to restrict sftp to that directory, you can check this guide on chroot example: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-sftp-without-shell-access-on-ubuntu-16-04